# Byte array to a file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a byte array for a file, is there a way to take that and save it has a file to a remote file server?

Comment: You need to decide on a protocol to transfer to the remote server and store it, e.g., HTTP, FTP or Windows File Sharing. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @dtb I'm just trying to take a file from within my website and transfer it to a remote file server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"\\server\public_share\MyFile.txt", byteArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing your data to file is the simple part and @aaron has shown you how...

```
i.e. File.WriteAllBytes(....etc
```

But something to be aware of, if you're transferring binary data over the wire and if your data contains bytes that could be interpreted as control characters then your data transfer will be problematic.

What you may need to do is encode your data first so that you can transfer it safely, typically you would use something like Base64 encoding.

You can use the Convert helper class to do that...

```
Convert.ToBase64String("file contents");
```

Comment: Huh? In what cases have you found that saving a binary file across the network will encounter the types of problems that you describe? Perhaps with FTP, if you don't specify binary mode or text-only protocols, but certainly not with Windows file sharing!

Comment: Hi Jim, with http transfers...not saying this is what he is doing...but it's a pretty common scenario when transferring data to file servers through port 80 to avoid firewall issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in the codebehind then you will need to use the FileStream and BinaryWriter objects.

Something like this;

```
FileStream filestream = new FileStream("myfile.txt", FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(filestream);

String msg = br.ReadString();
br.Close();
filestream.Close();

FileStream networkStream = new FileStream(@"\\server\share\file.txt", FileMode.Create);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(filestream);

bw.Write(msg);
bw.Close();
networkStream.Close();
```

If you're passing it through Javascript maybe using a HTML browse button then you'll need to do the same sort of thing but you will get the file stream from the post form request.

You may have an issue writing to the network location, if you're using IIS then you could set up a virtual directory and set the credentials in IIS.  The alternative is that you will need to do impersonation to write the file to the network server.

Mike